# How to change entire row/column to the same value in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, numpy-ndarray

So I have this 3d array

```
x = np.zeros((9, 9))
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

and I want to change all of row *x* and column *y* into 1

Desired output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

I am doing this on a 3d array with Booleans instead of 0s and 1s but I assume that the answers would be the same.

Comment: Just `ar[x] = 1`. For column `ar[:, y] = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use indexing with broadcasting:

```
x[n] = 1

# or
x[n, :] = 1
```

Example:

```
x[3] = 1

# x
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

For the second dimension:

```
x[:, n] = 1
```

Generic way for the **last** dimension:

```
x[..., n] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

So first index is for the rows, and second index is for the columns. In your example, if you want to set row n to 1 just do the following:

```
x[n] = 1
```

I hope this helps.